# RS485 isolated circuit - forgot connections. Will this work?

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, rs485, texas-instruments, isolated

below is my schematic for isolated RS485 section. FYI [B0305XT-1WR2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwie1IPos7LtAhXG63MBHRg9D70QFjACegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mornsun-power.com%2Fpublic%2Fuploads%2Fpdf%2FB_XT-1WR2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw32IAMA3-e3ndk4hvq43l4J) is used for power isolation and [ISO1500DBQ](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sllsf21d/sllsf21d.pdf?ts=1607017596467&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FISO1500DBQEVM) as transceiver.
As you can see I forgot to place GND & GND_RS485 connections at pins 2 & 15 respectively.
As per the TI datasheet's typical application circuit, they are connected to their respective GNDs.
I have checked my PCB also, tracks ended up just like the schematic.
So the question is -

1. Are the GND1 pins (2,8) & GND2 (9,15) are internally shorted? (I didn't find this info in datasheet) If yes, does my circuit work?

As of now, I've tried sending data from MCU to the transceiver. I cannot see any data on Serial terminal (connected D+,D- to USB-RS485 converter). Any help is appreciated.

[image: RS485-ISO1500DBQ]

Comment: Since you have the board in your hands, can you measure with a multimeter if the grounds are connected or not? Did you also connect the RS485-side ground to PC RS485 adapter ground?

Comment: There's continuity between respective GNDs. No I didn't connect the grounds. Never connected before but it used to work on other boards without common GND.

Comment: Power IC B0305XT-1WR2 is outputting 5.4V instead of its supposed 5V. It is same in 3 boards I checked. Does that pose a problem?

Comment: That's misuse of the part, since you have the capacitors there you have easy opportunity to solder a connection to a nearby ground.  As for debugging, break out the test equipment.  If you only have a meter, make a temporary firmware which commands transmit mode and a steady level from the MCU side and then measure the input and output of the RS485 chip, then try it with the other level.  Then command receive mode and drive the RS485 side from something else, possibly even a few flashlight cells held one way or the other.

Comment: How do you expect RS-485 to work without common reference between two devices, with simply two data wires? Mind you, that you specifically have GND_RS485 completely isolated and floating (unless they are connected to common ground with the PC via some other route). And the isolating might have a lot of common mode switching noise. This manufacturer does not seem to even care mentioning it. Also, the RS-485 chip consumes very little current, and the isolating supply minimum requirement is 20mA, so this explains why there is 5.4V, it is still within (but uncomfortably close) to the 5.5V limit.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I'll connect the GNDs and check. I'll update here asap.

Comment: @Justme - I never needed a common gnd while i was working with different boards and converters. yes 5.4V is on the edge, i will check with caps soldered to gnd, or by putting the ic off the board, or by non-isolating the transceiver.

Comment: @MANI It is possible that the boards and converters you used before had a common ground reference via some other wires like mains plugs or did not have fully isolated/floating RS485 port or had little common mode noise in their isolation. This design is fully isolated/floating, and my suspicion is that the isolating supply causes too much common mode noise that it does not work with only two data wires. Just connect PC ground to your floating RS485 ground like it should be connected to begin with and try if it solves the problem.

Comment: TO EVERYBODY AND FOR FUTURE REFERENCE - YOU MUST CONNECT GND PINS TO RESPECTIVE GNDS EVEN IF THE PINS (2,8) & (9,15) ARE INTERNALLY SHORTED. I GUESS IT IS ALL BECAUSE OF THE NOISE THAT IS PLAYING ON THE PCB/SIGNALS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Are the GND1 pins (2,8) & GND2 (9,15) are internally shorted? (I didn't find this info in datasheet) If yes, does my circuit work?

Likely.  Use a multimeter to verify.  Best practice is to connect all gnd pins to their respective ground.

> > I cannot see any data on Serial terminal (connected D+,D- to USB-RS485 converter

Check the level on your RE pin.  Looks like you signal controls both receive (RE) and transmit (DE).

Comment: Yes. The GNDS are internally shorted. Checked with meter. So you say it works if yes? Yeah DE and RE are shorted and controlled with a GPIO pin. I don't have oscilloscope to check signals.

Comment: Correct, the chip will work if the internal grounds are connected.  Having multiple ground pins helps with noise.  Your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Try swapping D+ and D- (or A and B). TI RS485 chips usually have polarity opposite to a standard, and A usually goes into D-.

Comment: @AndrejsGasilovs - Checked reversing the d+ and d- lines. No luck.

Comment: @Mr_Engineer - looks like caps are the problem. It's working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr_Engineer - sorry wrong comment. caps are already okay. i just forgot grounding the other side of caps. i made jumper connection with gnds and it started working.